# Why are my divs overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a parent div inside a list element that contains two children div for the left and right.  The left will contain an image and the right will contain two additional divs that contain some text and a timestamp.

I can't get the left and right divs to display without overlapping.

My HTML Looks like this:

```
<ul class="activity-comments">
<li>
<div style="border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
  <div style="float:left;border: solid 1px #0000ff;">
      <img src="http://localhost/new/img/sampleimg.png" class="thumb-small">
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>Some sample text here 1</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>Posted 1 day ago</small>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="border: solid 1px #ff0000;">
  <div style="float:left;border: solid 1px #0000ff;">
      <img src="http://localhost/new/img/sampleimg.png" class="thumb-small">
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>Some sample text here 2</small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <small>Posted 2 days ago</small>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Take a look at this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/57PQm/)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are overlapping because you  are floating a div, but aren't clearing the float.

Use the clearfix method to clear the float. Add a class `container` to your container divs and use this CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/57PQm/7/

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px #ff0000;
    zoom: 1; /* IE6&7 */
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.container:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

You'll also notice that I've removed your inline CSS. This makes your code easier to maintain.

Comment: It's not the worst thing in the world. It's a pretty common practice, but I did read somewhere how to do it without adding an extra div, but I don't remember it. I will look it up now.

Comment: It's a common practice by people who are still coding like its 2000 instead of 2013.  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/qDjdr

Comment: add a pseudoelement with `clear:left|right` or use `overflow` or simply adjust the image.

Comment: I fixed the solution to use clearfix and removed the inline css. And you don't have to lump me back to 2000...I'm pretty sure clearfix wasn't very common until at least like 2007.

Comment: @Travesty3 well, clearfixes greatest enemy was, of course, IE6 not being able to handle pseudoelements. So technically while XP is in it's last year of support some people still need to consider this. I always took the `overflow` fix which was pretty reliable.

Comment: Man CSS is so s**tty. When I compare this to native Android and iOS development CSS is so frustratingly slow and broken.

Comment: What is `zoom: 1` for?

Comment: @CrazyCoding This issue is 8 years old, so I don't remember very well, but according to the comment right next to it, it's for Internet Explorer 6 & 7. Probably no longer relevant

Comment: OK, thanks. Thought it'd be something for scaling or something.

Answer (score 0):

your thumbnail is setting the picture to a specific height of 41px. Either change the picture size, or change the div size or set the overflow of the outer div.

Comment: Where do you see the extra padding for the image?