# CSS Wordwrap not working as expected

Tags: css, html

Based on my earlier [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017893/why-are-my-divs-overlapping) I'm trying to use and understand the recommended way to align two divs horizontally using the overflow element.

With my short text the two divs align correctly, but when I add loner text it drops below the image.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and how do I fix it?

My **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/JVhQB/2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
<div class="left">
    <img src="http://localhost/new/img/sampleimg.png" class="wall-thumb-small" />
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
border: 1px solid #000000;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}

div.left {
padding:5px;
float: left;
}

div.right { 
float: left;
}

.thumb-small{
width:35px;
height:35px;
border: 1px solid #B6BCBF;
}
```

Comment: what's not working? can you post a printscreen of desired layout?

Comment: Take a look at my JSFiddle. I would expect the longer text to vertically align to the top of the right div but it doesn't

Comment: you need to specify a width. Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVhQB/4/

Comment: @karthikr I'm using a responsive-layout so defining a set width will not work.  Is there a better way?

Comment: use a `width:90%` (as a percentage of the space available)

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/JVhQB/16/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats expand to try to encompass their content. They generally expand up to the width of the containing region, regardless of how they are positioned. That is why it is going to a new line when the text is really long.

For what you are doing, I believe you want the image to the left of some text. This is done by having the outer region set with clearfix CSS (to always encompass all floats):

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 1px;
}
/* IE7+ */
*+html .container {
  min-height: 1%;
}
```

Then, only float your image to the left. Do NOT float your content. Add margins around the image as desired. So something like:

```
.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0; /* 10px on right and bottom */
}
```

The content in the div will then act like you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the float rule on the long text (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JVhQB/6/)**). When en element is floated after another floated element, it can't come before it vertically.

```
<div>
    <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here </div>
</div>
```

See the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) for the long version:

> The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top
>   of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the
>   source document.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set max-width attribute to restrict your text form taking as much space as available and to get maximum space its going to next line.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6BbD/1/

```
<div class="container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://localhost/new/img/sampleimg.png" class="thumb-small" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div style="word-wrap: break-word;max-width:400px">Some long text here Some long text here   Some long text here Some long text here Some long text here </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://localhost/new/img/sampleimg.png" class="thumb-small" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">Some short text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left;` on the rule and it will work. However, you may want to improve and test in ie 6+.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation says you should always set width on floated elements. 
the below link has great material to understand floats..

```
      http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/
```