# Using <h:outputStylesheet> makes <p:outputLabel> component invisible

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I have a rather strange issue with a webpage I'm working on in JSF. Basically, when I include the stylesheet for the website, using an h:outputStylesheet tag, the outputLabel component representing the document's title disappears.

The outputLabel is in the page source, and the rendered attribute = true, but it's invisible.

I'm using JSF2.2, PrimeFaces 5.1, OmniFaces 1.8 (though there aren't any omnifaces tags on the page), in netbeans with Glassfish 4.1. Testing in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Activity View</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="stylesheets" name="main.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="title" class="pageHeader">
            <pf:outputLabel value="Activity: [Title]: [Type]"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <pf:accordionPanel>
                <pf:tab title="Brief" >
                    <p>
                    </p>
                </pf:tab>
            </pf:accordionPanel>            
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.pageHeader{
font-size: x-large;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
```

}

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be the case? I've used this pattern elsewhere on the site without any issues.

Comment: Maybe you can get closer to the cause in Firebug - html tab - inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is `float: left;` - you can verify this by selecting the div and disabling the styles one by one in firebug:

[image]

The floating makes the divs overlap as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017893/why-are-my-divs-overlapping).

So you can either

- delete `float: left;`. Seems to make no difference with current code.
- put `style="clear: both"` on the div just below

and there are even more solutions, its called "clearfix".

Comment: Thank you, I had actually just got this far myself but it's great that you took the time to look at my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to solve the issue but could you try with the tag :

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui
```

instead of

```
xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

and for the outputLabel :

```
<p:outputLabel />
```

instead of

```
<pf:outputLabel />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it hasn't fixed it. Starting to wonder if it's a bug but I'm not confident enough in my knowledge of JSF to be certain.